# Installing npm package is having and issue related with sharp node modules

Tags: nodejs, npm

I am trying to install a GitHub repo in my ubuntu(18.04) machine. Try to run the command `npm install` but it never succeeded and hung up with an error.
[image]

Followed guide for [vue-storefront-api](https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront-api):

```
git clone https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront-api.git vue-storefront-api 
cd vue-storefront-api 
npm install
docker-compose up
```

Answer (score 1):

The needed file `glib-object.h` is located in `libglib2.0-dev` package ([see search results from packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=glib-object.h)).

Install it with

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

and then proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I installed `libglib2.0-dev` but facing the same issue again. Do I have to set some environment path or is there any other way?

Comment: Usually it is not needed. What software are you trying to compile?

Comment: I am trying to install `vue-storefront-api` and its having me an issue.

Comment: `locate glib-object.h | grep usr` results `/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib-object.h` though

Comment: You are compiling thing from here https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront-api ? Are you using Docker?

Comment: Yes that's what i am trying to do. Followed `git clone https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront-api.git vue-storefront-api`
`cd vue-storefront-api`
`npm install`
`docker-compose up`

Comment: But stucked while `npm install`